# Java monitor folder for files

Tags: java, spring, file, monitor, watchservice

I need to monitor a certain folder for new files, which I need to process.
I have the following requirements:

1. The filenames of the files are sequence numbers. I need to process each file in order. (Lowest number first, there's no guarantee that each sequence number exists. eg: 1,2,5,8,9
2. If files already exist in the folder during startup, I need to process them directly
3. I need a guarantee that I only process each file once
4. I need to avoid reading incomplete files (which are still being copied)
5. The service should ofcourse be reliable...

What is the most common way to accomplish this?

I'm using Java SE7 and Spring 4.

I already had a look at the WatchService of Java 7 but it seems to have problems with processing already existing files during startup, and avoid processing incomplete files.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html  -- And you will need to do your own persistence or some kind to recognize already processed files. Either move them to another directory, or put the filename in a database and check against it, etc.

Comment: The tutorial you're referring to is the one of the WatchService I mentioned in my question. How would you cope with 'incomplete files', the 'create' event will be fired before the file is actually completed. Also how would you solve the problem reading the files which are already present in the folder, during application startup?

Comment: In regards to the incomplete file issue, you need to coordinate with the application that is copying / writing the file.  General way would be to get a FileLock on it, assuming the writing application is well behaved and the OS being used supports file locking.  Otherwise you can have the writing application first write the file to a temp filename (with a different suffix) and then have it atomically moved to the file extensions you do process (most OSes support this).  As a last resort you can also monitor the file for a short period for file size changes (which is obviously not ideal).

Comment: @increment1 I believe trying to open the file for writing with an exclusive lock would suffice in most cases. If the file cannot be opened for writing, it means another process is writing to it and has not closed the handle.

Comment: @increment1 how would you handle the sorting requirement?

Comment: @Péé Depending on how many files are expected in the folder, I would probably just load the entire directory listing, sort it using an appropriate comparator, and then iterate through the sorted files for processing.  Unless you are expecting >10k files then I imagine this should be sufficient and by far the easiest, although possibly not the most optimized solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assembling comments into an answer.

Easiest way to parse the files in the correct order is to load the entire directory file listing into an array / list and then sort the list using an appropriate comparator.  E.g. Load files with `File.list()` or `File.listFiles()`.

This is not the most efficient methodology, but for less than 10,000 files should be adequate unless you need faster startup time performance (I can imagine a small lag before processing begins as all of the files are listed).

To avoid reading incomplete files you should acquire an exclusive `FileLock` (via a `FileChannel` which you can get from the `FileOutputStream` or `FileInputStream`, however you may not be able to get an exclusive lock from the `FileInputStream`) on the file.  Assuming the OS being used supports file locking (which modern OSes do) and the application writing the file is well behaved and holding a lock (hopefully it is) then as soon as you are able to acquire the lock you know the file is complete.

If for some reason you cannot rely on file locking then you either need to have the writing program first write to a temporary file (perhaps with a different extension) and then atomically move / rename the file (atomic for most OSes if on the same file system / partition), or monitor the file for a period of time to see if further bytes are being written (not the most robust methodology).